# JPA (Hibernate) OneToOne Impedance Mismatch

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I am studying JPA and Hibernate to build a Spring Boot webapp,  and there's something that bugs me. 
It is related to impedance mismatch in One To One relationships.

Let's say I have two domain entities, A and B, that have a one to one relationship.

This is what I would like to have:

- in the Java Classes, I would like to have A hold a reference to B;
- in the Database, I would like to have the table for "b" objects have a column with the foreign key to "a" keys.

Is there a way to do this with JPA and Hibernate in Spring Boot?

---

I report here the problem with real-world classes and code.

In my domain I have basically people and signatures.
Therefore, in my Java Code, I have Person @Entity and a Signature @Entity.

In Java, it makes sense to have the Person object own a Signature object.
So, here is the Person class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String lastName;

    // ??? which annotations?
    private Signature signature;

    // I omit constructors, getters and setters for brevity
```

And this is the Signature class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "signatures")
public class Signature {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Column(name="type")
    @NotNull
    private String type;

    @Column(name="image")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Lob
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType")
    private byte[] image;

    // I omit constructors, getters and setters for brevity
```

As you can see, Ids should be generated automatically, and I would like my Person class to have a reference to its Signature, and not vice-versa.

On the contrary, this is the DB schema I'd like to use:

```
CREATE SCHEMA signatures;

CREATE TABLE signatures.people (
   id BIGSERIAL,
   first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE signatures.signatures (
   id BIGSERIAL,
   type VARCHAR[16] NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR[100] NOT NULL,
   image BYTEA NOT NULL,
   person BIGINT NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_signature_people FOREIGN KEY (person) REFERENCES signatures.people (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

As you can see here, I would like the Signatures table to have a foreign key to the People table, and not vice-versa.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@OneToOne` mapping is a bit of an odd-ball. When the relationship is bi-directional, you can decide the owning side, but in a unidirectional relationship the declaring entity will always be the one with the foreign key.

One option is to make the relationship bi-directional, but hide the other direction in code.

The other way is to use a `@OneToMany` mapping, which will create the foreign key in the "many" table. This is also consistent with the database schema, as multiple child table rows could then link to the same parent row at least theoretically, especially if there's not a constraint to make sure they're unique.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work :(
I get the following error:
"referenced property unknown: com.demo.example.model.Signature.signatures"

It looks for the "signatures" attribute in the Signature object.

Comment: @AndreaRossi Ah, right. Any chance of making the link bi-directional?

Comment: You could either make it bi-directional and just prevent all access to the other direction (if that's really essential), or you can try using `@OneToMany`, which will create the foreign key to `Signature`, but you'll have a 1-sized `Set`. Seems it's impossible to get the foreign key on the reverse side with `@OneToOne`.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented it with the @OneToMany approach and it seems to work fine. Thank you for your support!
If you write a full answer on this workaround I will accept it :)